# Где в этом предложении расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: общие-вопросы

вот эта фотка по моему мнению, у тебя удалась.

Answer (score 2):

Вот эта фотка, по моему мнению, у тебя удалась. ("По моему мнению" -- вводное выражение, обособляется.)

Answer (score 1):

Да, это вводное словосочетание, указывающее на источник сообщения.